# How to sort a list and if the list element repeats, add the values associated with that element in tcl

Tags: tcl

My text file contains:

```
Inputs for graph -
0 32
1 0
2 38
3 0
4 74
5 0
6 78
1 47
2 84
```

I am trying to read this file and store in another file, but with modification that if 1st element repeats itself, add the values associated with those elements and store as one element.

```
Desired output -

0 32
1 47
2 122
3 0
4 74
5 0
6 78
```

Can someone guide me through this? I am doing it through tcl code.

Comment: Do you have those header lines too? There isn't a general way of dealing with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your input and output are both files of lines, with each line containing two simple integers where the first is your key and the second is your value, you can do this pretty easily.

```
set data {}

# Read in standard pattern
set f [open "input.txt"]
set rawdata [read $f]
close $f

# For each line...
foreach line [split $rawdata "\n"] {
    if {[string trim $line] eq ""} continue; # skip blank lines, just in case
    # Split the line into variables
    lassign $line key value
    # Accumulate, adding up the values for each key
    dict incr data $key $value
}

# Sort the result by the keys, type-punning the dict to a list
set data [lsort -stride 2 -index 0 -integer $data]

# Write the data back out
set f [open "output.txt" "w"]
foreach {key value} $data {
    puts $f "$key $value"
}
close $f
```

Comment: If you use `-index 1` then you will sort by the cumulative totals. The `-stride` option requires 8.6 or later.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!! Even i did it with creating a dict and appending the dict as we parse through each line. But i had never come across stride keyword, so thank you so much.